# how to invoke an event on a key press

Tags: graphics

I am making a gambling game in graphics. There are three polygons on  screen reading below 3, above 3 and throw a dice. I will incorporate random function generator in throw a dice area. And define two functions when a user enters the area of the rest of two polygons. But I am facing the problem of how to add functions here and how to invoke those function on keypress. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think should have mentioned the language you are using to code, In case of java swing i have a good solution.
Depending on where you want to trap the "enter" key, you could use an ActionListener (on such components such as text components or buttons) or attach a key binding to your component.
Here is the link how to use [Key binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public MyPanel() {

        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "onEnter");

        am.put("onEnter", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Enter pressed
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Actually i didn't understand your question, secondly if you are trying to nesting the events you can use threading i have link --[Threading with swing](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml).
you can check your question context here and apply it.

Ok and this is all for java, if you are working with other prog. language then please comment.

Thanks..